# How to set up a fixed header with a horizontal scrolling page?

Tags: html, css

**Background**

I've trying to design a website with a fixed header but with the rest of the page horizontally scrolling. The horizontally scrolling part will simply consist of a set of 6 images. The header will consist of the webpage name and a navigation bar.

**Problem**

I know i need to have the header set with the CSS property `Position:Fixed;`, which i have done so and is working as expected.

The problem is the rest of the page, I'm not sure what properties to set the div "Photoframe" which the photos sits in. The div "Photoframe"'s width needs to adjust dynamically as the dimensions of the photos will change when new photos are uploaded.

**What i have so far**

I have a "spacer" that is set with the height of the header and 100% width. This was to stop the photoframe from appearing stacked under the header. It kind of works. However when the user vertically scrolls the the page "photoframe" moves up and down and disregards the spacer.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="Header">
  <header>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Bass Clef Photography</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tagline">Passion 4 Live Music & Passion 4 Photography</div>
  </header>

  <div id="tabsContainer">
   <div class='tab zero'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="BassClef.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <div class='tab one'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab two'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab three'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab four'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class='tab five'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>







<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="photoframe">
      <div class="pics"> <img src="uploads/picture01.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture02.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture03.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture04.jpg" alt=""></div>
         <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture05.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="pics"> <img src="uploads/picture06.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture07.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture08.jpg" alt=""></div>
   </div>



   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

*, :before, :after {
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
    line-height: 1;

}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*End of CSS reset*/


a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}  /* visited link */
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {
    color: #030303;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}  /* selected link */

#Header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;




}



.spacer
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color:#424242;
}

.title{
    font-size: 6em;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tagline{
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #d3701e;
    margin-left: 30px;


}

#tabsContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#tabsContainer {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    height: 33px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li#active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
    font-size:24px;
}

.tab{
float: left;    
font-size:24px;
}

.tab.one
{
    width:190px;
    font-size:24px;
}

#photoframe
{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0px;

}

#photoframe .pics
{
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;


}

#photoframe .pics img {


    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display:inline-block;
}


.upload
{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add top:380px to #photoframe, this will fix the issue.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem? The photoframe still moves vertically when the browser is scrolled up and down.